# Destructive potential of vibration and shock on HDD?

Tags: hard-drive

My NAS is set in a Hifi style case on the TV bench. That TV bench has a sliding door. Lately, my 15-month-old boy has a game : slide the door back and forth to make it hit either side of the bench.

What are the risks for the NAS which is standing on it? Should I remove that door for now?

Answer (score 1):

Speaking as an engineer, this is quite a difficult question to answer. HDDs have a maximum shock (measured in g's) that they can withstand before they fail. Your son is administering a kinetic shock to the HDD every time he bangs the door which could be enough to kill it. I would also be concerned about the vibrations caused. Desktop hard drives are not designed for frequent sudden movement and data corruption is possible.

Speaking as the father of a 14-month-old... yeah, you probably need to do something... we put sponges on the doors in our house to lessen the impact. Or perhaps a cupboard safety lock would be appropriate?

Answer (score 0):

Most times, nothing will happen, however, if the head is spinning when the HDD is hit, it MAY cause it to scratch the surface, causing a bad sector situation. The cheapest solution is to avoid vibrations, either with some engineering or by discouraging your child to do so. Someone has already given you some ideas on this matter.

If this is not an option, I'd recommend you to use an SSD, which has no moving parts which can cause trouble. The downside is price, however samsung is making some nice disk with affordable prices on high capacity. Google for Samsung Evo, however, there may be some cheaper mark, I dont know.